# Refactor bat file ren command with wildcards to C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, command-line, filesystems

I'm looking to refactor a **bat file** into a **C# console application**. The main task of this bat file is to **move and rename files** using **wildcards**. I cannot find if there is anything in C# System.IO namespace (or other namespace) that can accomplish what I am trying to do.

Example input file:

```
D:\Testing\SrcDir\Input-20210318123001.txt
```

Desired output file:

```
D:\Testing\DestDir\Output-20210318123001.txt
```

Here is an example of the existing commands run that I am looking to convert to C#:

```
ren D:\Testing\SrcDir\Input-*.* Output-*.*
copy D:\Testing\SrcDir\Output-*.* D:\Testing\DestDir\
del D:\Testing\SrcDir\Output-*.*
```

My first thought was to simply use the `System.IO.File.Move` method. But this does not support wildcard usage. Neither does the `System.IO.File.Copy` method.

I'm trying to avoid using regex if possible (I have little to no experience with regex). I'd like to avoid rolling my own here if there is a simple solve for this that I have missed in my searching. Is there a good way to refactor this functionality into C#?

Comment: Use [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) to acquire a list of files matching your filter, then iterate over that list, moving them one at a time.

Comment: @jwdonahue This would require me writing my own parser that would handle copying whatever substring is in the place of `*.*` which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No you pass the search pattern to [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_), then you only get results that match your pattern for copying or whatever.

Comment: Then you would use [System.IO.FIle.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_Move_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) to move the file.

Comment: BTW: Your example batch file never worked. `ren D:\Testing\SrcDir\Input-*.* Output-*.*` will not work as expected. You'll have to do a bit more work than that, whether in batch or C#. But replacing the `Input-` part of the path string with `Output-` is a no brainer in either language.

Comment: See [string.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: I've tested the example batch file again and it is all working as expected for me. There is no more work required aside from what I've given in my example for doing this within a batch file.

Comment: Also, string.Replace for example would not handle the input file `D:\Testing\SrcDir\Input-Input-1234.txt` properly as it would replace both instance of "input-". The bat file using wildcards only replaces the first instance of "input-" which is the desired output.

Comment: I decided to stick with the batch file for now as it's working as intended. I may revisit this issue another time in the future.